# Traveling to the U.K. On a Jamaican passport from the United States

Tags: jamaican-citizens

I have a Jamaican Passport and a Updated Permenant Resident Card and I will be needing to travel to the United Kingdom for a total of 7 days . What other documents do I need for this trip ?

Answer (score 2):

To visit the UK for **tourism** purposes, [The holder of a Jamaican passport needs a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/jamaica/tourism).

It is your "*nationality as shown on your passport or travel document*" which matters. So far as I know, being a resident alien in the US does not confer any non-visa status or visa-waiver status.

I think that, although useful when re-entering the US, the permanent resident card is not regarded as a "travel document" you could use to enter the UK. Even if it were, it would not alter your nationality.

Comment: +1, you can make it clear that the Green Card means doodly-squat and they will not be able to board the flight.